# Why do my struct values not update in the following case when using two goroutines?

Tags: go, struct, goroutine

So, I'm very new to Go, started learning the language last weekend and created a basic character generator / autoroller for an RPG.
Since the generator does a lot of random number rolling until certain values are reached, I thought I might use goroutines to speed up processing.
This is my best effort so far but somehow during the final Printf I always get "STR: 0 DEX: 0" even though I can see during debugging that the two parallel functions are setting the values correctly.
The myCharacter struct is declared outside of them so I thought updating it should work fine?

This is my awful code. What I'm trying to achieve is roll for "STR" and "DEX" in parallel goroutines until one of them reaches an arbitrary condition (here a value of 1000000 for both just as a test).

Anybody can help me out why myCharacter.STR and myCharacter.DEX print out as 0 at the end?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Character struct {
    STR int
    DEX int
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    QuitChan := make(chan bool)

    myCharacter := new(Character)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-QuitChan:
                return
            default:
                mySTR, myDEX := RollChar()
                if mySTR >= 1000000 && myDEX >= 1000000 {
                    myCharacter.STR = mySTR
                    myCharacter.DEX = myDEX
                    QuitChan <- true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-QuitChan:
                return
            default:
                mySTR, myDEX := RollChar()
                if mySTR >= 1000000 && myDEX >= 1000000 {
                    myCharacter.STR = mySTR
                    myCharacter.DEX = myDEX
                    QuitChan <- true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    fmt.Printf("STR: %d DEX: %d", myCharacter.STR, myCharacter.DEX)
}

func RollChar() (int, int) {
    mySTR := rand.Intn(1000000) + 1
    myDEX := rand.Intn(1000000) + 1
    return mySTR, myDEX
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code is supposed to be doing? It seems like you're generating random numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 and rejecting them if they're not both 1,000,000 in two duplicate goroutines. What's the purpose?

Comment: @Schwern Well, this is only mock-up code for learning how to do goroutines that I would wrap in some timing function to test the performance. I needed it to run a lot of times so I chose 1 000 000 for both values.
In truth I would be rolling 2d6 (so rand.Intn(6) + rand.Intn(6) + 2) and checking stats against CLI flags like -minSTR and -minDEX (if mySTR >= minSTR && myDEX >= minDEX).
You can see my actual generator here:
https://github.com/Lim-Dul/mausGo

Comment: For something as simple as generating a random number and checking bounds, all the switching between goroutines might make it slower, but give it a shot. Consider instead having one goroutine which feeds valid random numbers to a channel and everything else reads from that channel. That avoids the sort of sync issues Burak mentions.

Comment: I'll try that, @Schwern, it will be a good exercise to learn about goroutines as well. :)
Though I need the parallelization improvement on the random number generation part (basically parallelize the dice throwing), not the checking part. Maybe two goroutines that throw in randomized structs into a channel and then one listener that checks their attributes against bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goroutines never run. main does not wait for goroutines to complete, it prints and quits before they execute.

This can be solved with [WaitGroups](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) to make main wait until all goroutines are done. Its basically a fancy counter.

```
    // Create the WaitGroup
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Add one thing to wait for.
    // This must be done outside the goroutine to ensure it's added
    // before `wg.Wait()` is called.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        # When the goroutine exits, say this one thing is done.
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            ...
        }
    }()

    // Same for the next one.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            ...
        }
    }()

    // Wait until the two things in the WaitGroup are done.
    wg.Wait()
    
    fmt.Printf("STR: %d DEX: %d", myCharacter.STR, myCharacter.DEX)
```

That will get your goroutines running. Next is to not cut & paste the code, and use a loop.

```
    for i:= 0; i < 2; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                myCharacter.STR = 42;
                myCharacter.DEX = 23;
                break;
            }
        }()
    }
```

Note that if you expect both values to be 1,000,000 that will take 1,000,000,000,000 tries (1 trillion). Two goroutines will not make that much faster.

Comment: That's it! Man, I'm so stupid, I fell into the very pitfall that was explicitly mentioned in a tutorial on YouTube I watched. I was already wondering why the program is exiting so quickly.
And even my sending the message on the QuitChan channel to the other goroutine works as expected. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Chaeska It's a pretty common pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

You have a data race. Your two goroutines are accessing shared variables without any explicit synchronization. You need to use a mutex in this case to ensure mutual exclusion as well as the visibility of changes made in one goroutine in others.

Declare a mutex:

```
myCharacter := new(Character)
mutex:=sync.Mutex{}
```

Use the mutex when you read/write the shared variables:

```
mutex.Lock()
myCharacter.STR = mySTR
myCharacter.DEX = myDEX
mutex.Unlock()
```

Also:

```
mutex.Lock()
fmt.Printf("STR: %d DEX: %d", myCharacter.STR, myCharacter.DEX)
mutex.Unlock()
```

Without mutex, there is no guarantee that modifications made to a shared variable are visible to other goroutines.

Comment: Thanks for the information - from that alone I will have learned for the future. However, altering my code as described still results in '0' being printed at the end.
I added ther mutex.Locks to both goroutines and around the Printf like you suggested.